# Calculated Column Menu Option Disabled in Spotfire

Tags: reporting, spotfire

I am a complete rookie to spotfire and am trying to create a calculated column but the menu option is disabled and can't figure out why. It feels like something thats really simple. Can anyone help me out? My data source is a connection to a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if there is no data loaded, the *Insert Calculated Column* option will not be active.

Second, if you're using an in-database connection (not an Information Link), then you cannot insert calculated columns. In fact, with in-db connections, there's a lot of things you *can't* do:

- Insert Columns
- Insert Rows
- Insert Calculated Column
- Insert Binned Column
- Data Relationships
- K-means Clustering
- Line Similarity
- Data Functions
- Regression Modeling
- Classification Modeling
- Insert Predicted Columns

But ... if you have data loaded and you're not using an in-database connection, I suspect the License for inserting a calculated column is not enabled for you. I don't know if you are an Administrator or not, but here is what I would recommend that an Administrator do.

Open the Administration Manager (Tools > Administration Manager). On the *Users* tab, search for your username and select it. Then, to the right, click the *Licenses* tab.

I believe the license for inserting calculated columns is under *TIBCO Spotfire Professional* and then *Insert New Column*. Make sure that's checked. If it is, then I'm not sure what the problem is. If it's not checked (i.e., there's a red X), then you'll have to go to the Groups and Licenses tab and Edit the Licenses for either yourself or the Group you belong to.

Be sure to look in the Spotfire Deployment & Administration manual if you haven't already: [docs.tibco.com](http://docs.tibco.com)

I think this will get you close. You might consider posting in the Tibcommunity as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks...one of our more experienced spotfire guys figured it out with me but definitely helpful. I was using an in db connection. I didn't realize the data export was as easy as it is.